# Как с помощью javascript нажать кнопки клавиатуры? (аналог HTMLElement.click() у мышки)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью `javascript` нажать кнопки клавиатуры?

У левой кнопки мыши например: `HTMLElement.click()`

Нужен аналог для клавиатуры. И чтобы можно было запустить через инструмент разработчиков devtool.

*P.S. нет ничего невозможного!*

Comment: Это невозможно по той же причине, по которой нельзя на js читать файлы - из соображений безопасности.

Comment: используйте new Event https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: Можно подробнее про new Event? т.е. через консоль разработчика можно нажать клавиши клавиатуры (как в случае с мышкой click())? Например через консоль разработчика нажать ctrl+D чтобы вкладку сохранить. А если это просто ждет команды от пользователя чтобы нажал клавишу реальной клавиатуры, то new Event не подходит для этих целей

Comment: Насчёт devtool не скажу, но если обработчик переназначается, то достаточно вызвать его с соответствующим аргументом. А если предыдущий обработчик сохраняется и вызывается, то вообще не вижу проблем.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript

Comment: @Ilnyr по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/q/596481/3208225 есть куча вариантов, правда я какой не пробовал почему то не сработал ни один, или я что то не так делал, гляньте, может у вас получится

Answer (score 3):

Очень просто listener, даже без jq

```js
document.addEventListener ('keydown', function (event){
    console.log (event);
}); 
var evt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode':65, 'which':65});
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: Это же обнаружение нажатии клавиш, не то. Внимательно посмотрите мой вопрос "нажать кнопки клавиатуры с помощью javascript без использования реальной клавиатуры"

Comment: @Ilnyr: посмотрите внимательнее. Код делает именно то, что Вы хотите

Answer (score 2):

Используя Jquery:

```js
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress"); 
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 40; // код клавиши, в данном случае — пробел
$("body").trigger(press);  // имитация
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Помоему не работает. Можно подробнее, что делает этот код?

Answer (score 0):

В подобной ситуации я тоже использовал обработчик события addEventListener. К примеру, я использовал код ниже для выхода из модального окна через Esc.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            overlay.style.display = 'none';
            more.classList.remove('more-splash');
            document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';    
        }
    });
```

Аналогично можно использовать и Enter для своих операций.

Answer (score 0):

click() не нажимает кнопку мыши, а запускает обработчики события click в коде. Реальное нажатие кнопки мыши генерирует несколько событий кроме click, это допустим mousedown, mouseup и др.

Так и для клавиатуры это может быть keypress, keyup, keydown, а также событие input и др.

Поэтому, допустим, если на каком то сайте для эмуляции нажатия Enter необходимо выполнить keypress, то на другом сайте это может уже не сработать. Все зависит от обработчиков событий на странице.

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = e.keyCode = 13;
$("textarea").trigger(e);
```

Comment: возможно ли вашим примером эмулировать ctrl+d чтобы сохранить в закладку? Если да, то как это делать?

Comment: Нельзя эмулировать вообще никаких нажатий в том смысле в котором вы думаете это работает. Иначе это была бы дыра в безопасности.